# Get the lowest price list on an article->product relationship

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I think the title is no very accurate but I don't know how to better describe it.

My model looks like this:

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    supplier = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True)
    ean = models.CharField(max_length=42, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('Products', unique=True)

class Products(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    eans = models.TextField(blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=9000, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
    brand_id = models.ForeignKey('Brands', unique=True, db_column='brand_id')
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('Categories', unique=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
```

What I'd like to do is to get a list of products (optionally filtered by categories, brand, supplier, price...) with the lowest price and supplier for that product. Keep in mind that there usually is more than one article for each product (each article has a supplier but two suppliers can sell the same product).

I'd like to get this list on the most efficient way but it takes ages to do something like this:

```
Products.objects.select_related().filter(articles__supplier__in=("Supplier1","Supplier2")).filter(category_id__in=(413,678,699,736,770)).filter(articles__stock__gt=0).annotate(mp=Min("articles__price"))
```

This is the sql query django generates:

```
SELECT `products`.`id`, `products`.`eans`, `products`.`model`, 
    `products`.`description`,`products`.`name`, `products`.`brand_id`,
    `products`.`category_id`, `products`.`image`, 
    MIN(`articles`.`price`) AS `mp`,

FROM `products` 

LEFT OUTER JOIN `articles` ON (`products`.`id` = `articles`.`product_id`) 
    INNER JOIN `categories` ON (`products`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`) 
    INNER JOIN `articles` T4 ON (`products`.`id` = T4.`product_id`) 
    INNER JOIN `brands` ON (`products`.`brand_id` = `brands`.`id`) 

WHERE (`articles`.`supplier` IN ("Supplier1", "Supplier2") 
    AND `products`.`category_id` IN (413, 678, 699, 736, 770) 
    AND T4.`stock` > 0 ) 

GROUP BY `products`.`id`, `products`.`id`, `products`.`eans`, `products`.`model`, 
    `products`.`description`, `products`.`name`, `products`.`brand_id`, 
    `products`.`category_id`, `products`.`image`  

ORDER BY NULL
```

And I'm not even getting the supplier name for that price! (I don't know of a way to get it).

What's the best way to do this in an efficient way? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Afaik django creates the group by and I think the efficiency problem comes from there. I've add the sql query django generates to output that queryset. There you can see the multiple group by statements.

Comment: `Articles` has `product_id = models.ForeignKey('Products', unique=True)` then this cannot be true : _... but two suppliers can sell the same product_. Unless you create different record/row of product for each supplier.

Comment: Exactily, each different product sold by a supplier is an Articles row. If two suppliers sell the same product they'll have two different rows in the Articles table liked with a single row on the Products table (where the product information is: description, brand...). This is kind of a product unifying system between different suppliers.

Comment: @Nacho: I repeat : with `unique=True` you _cannot_ have two Article with a same product_id. That's what `unique` means, you know ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sorry, you are right. This model was autogenerated form an existing table and didn't check it out. Let's see if that helps.

Comment: Select_related() in this query does nothing because nothing is passed in it. You should pass 'supplier' to it

Answer (score 3):

First of all you shuold discover which tables are in your database and what relations are there, because one model does not mean one table (it is up to Django to deside). And you should also know how the tables are called. Usually the name consist of name_of_django_app, then underscore and then name of model.
Second, you can always do raw queries to your database using Django.

Something like 
some_list = list(Products.objects.raw
('`select articles.supplier,articles.id,articles.ean,articles.model,articles.price,
articles.stock,products.ean,products.model,products.description,products.name,products.imag 
from articles 
join products on products.id = articles.product_id 
where articles.price = (select min(articles.price) from articles)`'))